# How to separate strings and tuples from list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tuple and string values. Like as below

```
lst = [
       'ACER', (['1000.0'], None),
       'ACER', (['1000.0'], None),
       'HP', (['1000.0'], None),
       'ACER', (['1001.0'], None),
       'ACER', (['1001.0'], None),
       'ACER', (['1001.0'], None),
       'ACER', (['1001.0'], None),
       'HP', (['1001.0'], None)
      ]
```

Have to separate it as a list of strings and list of tuples. And also remove duplicate of strings and tuples.

I need the result like as:

```
Str_lst = ['ACER', 'HP']
tup_lst = [(['1000.0'], None), (['1001.0'], None)]
```

Note: I have more than 80000 values in list so please give me best performance solution as well

Comment: how will you know which tuple corresponds to hp or acer?

Comment: `isinstance(object, class-or-type-or-tuple)` could help you and a `set` to remove duplicates.

Comment: @yoopoo, problem with that is, you can't put lists in a set - they're mutable. It works for the strings, though.

Comment: @TomZych true i meant that for the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
>>> tup = [lst[x+1] for x in range(0, len(lst), 2)]
>>> names = [lst[x] for x in range(0, len(lst), 2)]
>>> b = []
>>> [b.append(x) for x in tup if x not in b]
>>> b
[(['1000.0'], None), (['1001.0'], None)]
>>> list(set(names))
['ACER', 'HP']
```

This might be best solution, but it will help to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Simple just check is the element is `instance of tuple`. if it is tuple append to the tupl_list

```
lst = [
       'ACER', (['1000.0'], None),
       'ACER', (['1000.0'], None),
       'HP', (['1000.0'], None),
       'ACER', (['1001.0'], None),
       'ACER', (['1001.0'], None),
       'ACER', (['1001.0'], None),
       'ACER', (['1001.0'], None),
       'HP', (['1001.0'], None)
      ]
tupl_list=[]
normalist=[]
for i in lst:       
    if isinstance(i,tuple):
        tupl_list.append(i)
    else:normalist.append(i)
```